# In TypeScript, can we use "runtime" keys for defining a new type?

Tags: typescript

Better explain this as an example:

```js
class ModuleOptions {
  key1?: string;
  key2?: string;

  keyA?: string;
  keyB?: string;
}

class Module {
  static options: ModuleOptions = {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2',

    keyA: 'keyA',
    keyB: 'keyB'
  };

  static create(options: ModuleOptions) {
    Object.assign(Module.options, options);
  }
}


const myModule = Module.create({
  key1: 'foo'
});

// Now Module.options static field has "foo" as key1...
// Could we constrait fooArgs to have a property named "foo" of type string?
function foo(fooArgs: NewType) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

It's possible to make `fooArgs` (that is, `NewType`) to only accept `'foo'` as key, with the same type defined for it (`string`)?

This is not working (even making it simple):

```
class NewType {
  [k in keyof [ModuleOptions.options]]: string;
}
```

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get something like what you want, but there are definitely pain points.  The first major problem is that TypeScript doesn't allow you to arbitrarily mutate the types of existing values.  So if a variable named `foo` has type `string`, you can't change it to `number` later.  In your case, if `Module.options.key1` is known by the compiler to be the [string-literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `"key1"`, then you can't change its type to the string-literal type `"foo"` later.  The compiler will expect it to be `"key1"` forever, even after you call `Module.create()`.   There are a few ways around this.  One is using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to *narrow* the type of a value (types of values can get more specific, but they can't change arbitrarily), and another is to use new variables to represent the value of the new type.

Here's a possible solution using the latter method... have `create` return a new version of `Module` with a different type:

```
module Module {

  type Module = typeof Module; // handy type alias

  const defaultOptions = {
    key1: 'key1' as 'key1',
    key2: 'key2' as 'key2',
    keyA: 'keyA' as 'keyA',
    keyB: 'keyB' as 'keyB',
  }; // use type assertions to narrow to string literals

  type DefaultOptions = typeof defaultOptions; // handy type alias

  export const options: Record<keyof DefaultOptions, string> = defaultOptions;

  // represent overwriting properties from T with properties from U
  type Assign<T, U> = { 
    [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof U ? U[K] : K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never 
  };

  export function create<T>(
    o: T
  ): { [K in keyof Module]: 'options' extends K ? Assign<DefaultOptions, T> : Module[K] } {
    Object.assign(options, o);
    return Module as any; // can't represent type mutation, use type assertion here
  }

}
```

That uses [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to represent what happens to `options` when you call `create`.  Let's see how it works:

```
const almostMyModule = Module.create({
  key1: 'foo'
});
almostMyModule.options.key2; // "key2"
almostMyModule.options.key1; // string? oops
```

Oops, the type of the parameter passed to `create()` is inferred as `{key1: string}`, not `{key1: "foo"}`.  This is another pain point.  There are ways to get the inference to be correct, but for now I'll just use a type assertion to narrow it:

```
const myModule = Module.create({
  key1: 'foo' as 'foo'
});
myModule.options.key1; // 'foo', that's better
myModule.options.key2; // 'key2'
```

Now that `myModule.options.key1` is known by the compiler to be `"foo"`, we can make that `NewType` you wanted:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type NewType = { [K in ValueOf<typeof myModule.options>]: string };
```

Inspecting `NewType` gives us:

```
// type NewType = {
//   foo: string;
//   key2: string;
//   keyA: string;
//   keyB: string;
// }
```

And you can use it:

```
function foo(fooArgs: NewType) {
  fooArgs.foo // okay
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!