# How to write a function that adds a field to array of objects with typechecking?

Tags: typescript

I want to "decorate" an array of objects by adding a field to them. 
I want to create a function that adds a user specified field with user specified value to each object in that array.

Problem is I don't know how to write such a function.

This does not even compile.

```
  public static addField<T extends object>(
    array: T[],
    field: string,
    value: any,
  ): Array<T extends { [field]: string}> {
    return array.map((object) => ({ ...object, [field]: value }));
  }
```

This doesn'work.

```
  public static addField<T extends object>(
    array: T[],
    field: string,
    value: any,
  ): T[] {
    return array.map((object) => ({ ...object, [field]: value }));
  }
```

Comment: With the field name being completely dynamic like that, I don't think you can make this typesafe. Does the field name **have** to be a parameter?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282054/in-typescript-can-we-use-runtime-keys-for-defining-a-new-type

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using an intersection and `Record`, but some assertions are needed

```
class x {
    public static addField<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
        array: T[],
        field: K,
        value: V
    ): Array<T & Record<K, V>> {
        const addedValue = { [field]: value } as Record<K, V>
        return array.map((o) => ({ ...o, ...addedValue }));
    }
}

x.addField([{ a: 1 }], "b", "").map(_ => _.a + _.b)
```

Comment: I'm blown away by the fact that this doesn't even require that the key be given as a literal in the call. Wow.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow avoid `as`?

Comment: @zerkms unfortunately not, computed property types are only strictly typed if ts is sure the computed property can only ever be one specific value, otherwise it will default to `{ [s: string]: type }`,